# What is the difference between Python lists and numpy matrices

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

What is the difference between:

```
x = [1, 4, 3];
print('x = ')
print(x)
y = [0, -1, -2];
print('y = ')
print(y)
```

AND

```
x = numpy.matrix('1;2;3') 
print('x = ')
print(x)
y = numpy.matrix('0;-1;-2')
print('y = ')
print(y)
```

Comment: one is using native python and the other numpy? Run them in a python interpreter and see for your self :-) What is your question?

Comment: using:- x=[1,4,3]; x[0,1]=9; gives type error ; while using x=numpy.matrix['1';'2';'3']; x[1,0]=5 doesnt ....why?

Comment: since list indices must be integers, not tuple in python.